# Azure authentication error when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, azure-keyvault

I'm using the **Azure C# API** to get data from an **Azure Keyvault**:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
    ManagedIdentityClientId = "abcdef-1234-5678-9101-11213ghi"
});
var kvUri = $"https://kv-abc.vault.azure.net";
var secretName = "MySecret";

var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), credential);
var secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName);
```

When debugging in Visual Studio 2022 I get an **HTTP 401 error** at `secretClient.GetSecret(secretName)`:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'
```

But when running **without debugging** (e.g. via CTRL-F5 or the CMD) it works!

I've tried to:

- start without debugging then attach the debugger
- clean the solution
- log out then log in again in Visual Studio
- reboot Windows
- delete `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.IdentityService`
- all of the above

How to fix or workaround this issue?

Comment: What is the framework and Version of your app?

Comment: Please share your .csproj file.

Comment: Debugging locally or remote debugging?

Comment: @Harshitha .NET Framework 4.8
Locally
I can't share the .csproj as it belongs to my customer but let me know what specific  section/settings we can have a look at.
Thanks and best regards :)

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the secret value? Try to print it and check.

Comment: Where you have written the code to retrieve the KV secret ? In Controller Action method ?

Comment: @Harshitha Debug locally.
Yes I get the secret value when not debugging, I display it into the console.
No it's a standard EXE, executed on Windows.

Comment: You have mentioned `Azure C# API` in the question.

Comment: You are providing the option for `ManagedIdentityClientId`. Once try with the below code without DefaultAzureCredentialOptions and check. `var kvUri = $"https://sfkeyvault4oct.vault.azure.net/";
  var secretName = "MySecret";
  var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), credential);
  var KVSecret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName);
  Console.WriteLine(KVSecret.Value.Value);`

Comment: Iam not getting any error with debugger as well. Even I have tried with your code.

Comment: @Harshitha Unfortunately same issue without specifying any options: OK with CTRL-F5, KO with F5. By the way AFAIK the Managed Identity is not used during development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255518/discussion-between-harshitha-and-pragmateek).